# Error in installing pypiwin32

Tags: python, python-3.x, win32com, msg

I want to parse `*.msg`-files with Python and I need to import `win32com.client`

When importing I'm getting an error saying that the module is not. I thin tried to install `pypiwin32`:

```
pip install pypiwin32
```

Which gives me error :

```
   import _winreg
ImportError: No module named _winreg
```

I've attached a screenshot for a better understanding of the problem. Is this only for Windows? – I am highly confused.

A suggested alternate way of parsing the `.msg`-file with Python would also be appreciated.

I am using Ubuntu 17.10.

The code:
[image]

Error screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `pypiwin32` package only works on Windows, where the Windows APIs are available.

A possible alternative would be to use https://github.com/mattgwwalker/msg-extractor, or re-use the code in that project.